# How to keep number from a Firestore Query in a variable for further usage?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to keep the number I am querying from a document in a collection in firestore and save that number in a local variable in an angular component to use it within other methods in that component.

I already tried to implement the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51434043/9245344) provided by Ittu, but that did not work for me, since I did not understood where to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

this is my code:

```
var magNum: number;

docRef.ref.get().then(
  function(doc) {
  console.log("Document data:", doc.get('painPoint'));
  magNum = doc.get('painPoint');
});

console.log('number \n' + magNum);
```

The result in the console is `undefined`, except if I put it into the function like:

```
var magNum: number;

docRef.ref.get().then(
  function(doc) {
  console.log("Document data:", doc.get('painPoint'));
  magNum = doc.get('painPoint');
  console.log('number \n' + magNum);
});
```

then magNum will be 3 in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to learn something about callback functions and promises.

Look at your code:

```
var magNum: number;

docRef.ref.get().then(
  function(doc) {
  console.log("Document data:", doc.get('painPoint'));
  magNum = doc.get('painPoint');
});

console.log('number \n' + magNum);
```

The code flow looks like the following:

1. You declare a variable `magNum` as number
2. You say: "get the document from firestore and if you done, THEN store the `painPoint` number to the `magNum` variable"
3. Print out my `magNum` from firestore.

But what really happens is this:

1. The code declares a new variable `magNum` as number
2. The code starts to get your document from firestore **ASYNC**
3. The code prints out your `magNum` (Which is undefined, because getting the firestore document isn't done yet)
4. After some times the document is loaded and your variable `magNum` will be set to the value of `painPoint`.

**Consolusion**: `console.log('number \n' + magNum);` will be called before the line `magNum = doc.get('painPoint');` and this is why `magNum` is `undefined` in **console**!

You can use **async/await**:

```
async yourFunction(...){
    var magNum: number;

    var doc = await docRef.ref.get();
    magNum = doc.get('painPoint');

    console.log('number \n' + magNum); // output is the value of painPoint
}
```

Comment: I found something where I could use `await`, but do not know how to implement it since the function within the `then`-construction is not an async function where I could use `await` --- sorry posted that comment to late for your answer update

Comment: thank you very much, that was the end of a very long story! :)