# How to use async/await for firestore in combination with chart.js?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, chart.js, linechart

I would like to fill a linechart which I implemented with the framework [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) using data from documents in firestore.  But the async/await construction used for putting the data into a number array, prohibits filling the chart-data property.

I got there through the question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54053384/how-to-keep-number-from-a-firestore-query-in-a-variable-for-further-usage) about the usage of async/await for getting data from firestore and save it in a variable, but did not find resources concerning the combination with the chart.js framework.

this is my code for setting the chart properties and setting the chart-data array in the async ngOnInit-method

```
public barChartOptions = {scaleShowVerticalLines: false, responsive: true};
public barChartLabels = ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'];
public barChartType = 'line';
public barChartLegend = true;
public barChartData = [{data: [], label: 'Schmerzen'}];

constructor(public firebaseService: FirebaseService) {
}

async ngOnInit() {
  var numAr: number[];
  console.log('inside myData onInit ' + numAr)
  this.barChartData[0].data = await this.firebaseService.getUserState();
  //this.barChartData[0].data = [1,0,10,7]
}
```

`getUserState()` is an async method in a firebaseService (Angular-Component) and returns a `number[]` which I already confirmed, so it is not an issue of unequal datatypes

the `console.log` works and I see two numbers (`numAr` just contains two numbers for now) in the console, but the step after that - the assignment - does not work. If I use the uncommented hardcoded version the chart shows the curve properly.

Comment: console.log an uninitialized variable?  how about, as an effective debug step: `let result = await this.firebaseService.getUserState(); console.log(result); this.barChartData[0].data = result;`

Comment: Async/await is not the problem.. please show us the code of your getUserState()..